# F# - How to sort a list by descending and then by ascending?

Tags: sorting, f#

I have the following short code that simply counts words of a text:

```
[<EntryPoint>]  
let main argv =   
    let text = File.ReadAllText("gettysburg.txt").ToLower()  
    Regex.Split(text, "\W+")  
    |> Seq.groupBy id  
    |> Seq.map (fun (k, grp) -> (k, grp |> Seq.length))  
    |> Seq.sortByDescending (fun (w, ln) -> (ln, w))  
    |> Seq.iter (fun (k, ln) -> printfn "%s\t%i" k ln)
```

The sort function is sorting first by the number of occurrences, and then by the word in alphabetical order, both descending. I need to do it descending by occurrences, but then ascending by alphabetical order.

With LINQ is very easy with *OrderByDescending* and *ThenBy*. How I achieve the same result in F# without recurring to LINQ?

Thank you.

Comment: you can use the LINQ Methods just as you would in C#

Comment: by the way: just changing your code to `Seq.sortBy (fun (w, ln) -> (-ln, w))` should work just fine

Comment: As quick answer: `Seq.sortBy` of negate of number of occurrences, then by word in alphabetical order: `:> Seq.sortBy (fun(w, ln) -> (-ln, w))`.

Comment: @Carsten What if both members were strings? You cannot invert the sign in that case...

Comment: Gustavo gave an answer to this ... but you gave the question with `int` so why should I generalize unnecessary?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `sortBy` instead and make negative the number of occurrences:

```
|> Seq.sortBy (fun (w, ln) -> (-ln, w))
```

Alternatively, if you run into more complicated cases you can use the function `sortWith` which uses a comparer function:

```
|> Seq.sortWith (fun (w1, ln1) (w2, ln2) -> compare (ln2, w1) (ln1, w2))
```

In fact the first solution is a short-cut for your specific case because you can make the number negative, but if you have more fields, not numeric, then by using `sortWith` you can achieve the same as with `OrderBy` ... `ThenBy` in Linq, by ordering the tuple and swapping the elements when it's descending.

Note that both alternatives rely on [structural comparison](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2009/11/08/equality-and-comparison-constraints-in-f-1-9-7.aspx) over tuples.

Comment: So... in a supposed case of sorting not integers but just a couple of strings , would I have to resort to the sortWith method?

Comment: Probably yes, specially if you want those strings to be sorted ascending and descending in one shot.

Answer (score 4):

Sorting numbers descending is the same as sorting the negative numbers ascending (because if `a <= b` then `-b <= -a`) so this should work:

```
[<EntryPoint>]  
let main argv =   
    let text = File.ReadAllText("gettysburg.txt").ToLower()  
    Regex.Split(text, "\W+")  
    |> Seq.groupBy id  
    |> Seq.map (fun (k, grp) -> (k, grp |> Seq.length))  
    |> Seq.sortBy (fun (w, ln) -> (-ln, w))  
    |> Seq.iter (fun (k, ln) -> printfn "%s\t%i" k ln)
```